# Unable to gossip with any seeds cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I installed Data Stax 3.7 on my Windows machine(IP:10.175.12.249) and made following changes in my cassandra.yaml file:

cluster_name: 'Test_cluster' 
listen_address: "10.175.12.249"
start_rpc: true
rpc_address: "0.0.0.0" 
broadcast_rpc_address: "10.175.12.249"
seeds: "10.175.12.249" 
endpoint_snitch:  SimpleSnitch

Now, I started the service and cassandra is running fine on seed node.

I tried adding another node to my cluster. So I installed Data Stax 3.7 on another Windows machine(IP:192.168.158.78) and made following changes in cassandra.yaml file:

cluster_name: 'Test_cluster' 
listen_address: "192.168.158.78"
start_rpc: true
rpc_address: "0.0.0.0" 
broadcast_rpc_address: "192.168.158.78"
seeds: "10.175.12.249" 
endpoint_snitch:  SimpleSnitch

Now when I started the cassandra service on my 2nd machine, I am getting the following error:

```
INFO  09:41:27 Cassandra version: 3.7.0
INFO  09:41:27 Thrift API version: 20.1.0
INFO  09:41:27 CQL supported versions: 3.4.2 (default: 3.4.2)
INFO  09:41:27 Initializing index summary manager with a memory pool size of 100 MB and a resize interval of 60 minutes
INFO  09:41:27 Starting Messaging Service on /192.168.158.78:7000 (Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6235)
INFO  09:41:27 Scheduling approximate time-check task with a precision of 10 milliseconds
Exception (java.lang.RuntimeException) encountered during startup: Unable to gossip with any seeds
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any seeds
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1386)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision(StorageService.java:561)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:855)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:725)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:625)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:370)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:585)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:714)
ERROR 09:41:58 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any seeds
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1386) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision(StorageService.java:561) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:855) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:725) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:625) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:370) [apache-cassandra-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:585) [apache-cassandra-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:714) [apache-cassandra-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
WARN  09:41:58 No local state or state is in silent shutdown, not announcing shutdown
INFO  09:41:58 Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
```

Below is the output of nodetool status on seed node(IP:10.175.12.249):
C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra\bin>nodetool status

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
========================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
DN  192.168.158.78  ?          256          68.1%             6bc4e927-3def-4dfc-b5e7-31f5882ce475  rack1
UN  10.175.12.249   257.76 KiB  256          65.7%             300d731e-a27c-4922-aacc-6d42e8e49151  rack1
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Disable the firewall and SELINUX and try again

Answer (score 7):

The `- seeds:` in conf/cassandra.yaml should have the same value (same IP or the hostname) as `listen_address:` in the same conf file.

I came across this error when the IP addresses were not matching. Try keeping the same and restart the cluster. Hope this helps...

Comment: what should be the address in seed and listen address. It should be the its own ip address(192.168.158.78) or the other node Ip address(10.175.12.249).